# Swift: How to remove "+" and country code from suggested phone number autofill in UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uikit

When you set a UITextField's `textContentType` to `.telephoneNumber`, a suggested phone number will appear when you engage the text field.

[image: suggested phone number above keyboard]

When you tap the suggestion, the text field's text becomes the suggested phone number with the "+1" at the beginning. However, my text field has a drop down for users to select the country code so I don't want the "+1" to be included. Is there a way I can detect if the suggestion has been tapped and remove the "+1" from that text in the text field?

Comment: You should get a "valueChanged" event on the text field. The `shouldChangeCharactersIn` delegate may also be called.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this...

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var yourTextfield: UITextField!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        yourTextfield.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFiedDidChange(_:)), for: .editingChanged)
    }


    @objc func textFiedDidChange(_ sender: Any) {
        let prefix = "+1" // What ever you want may be an array and step thru it
        guard yourTextfield.text!.hasPrefix(prefix) else { return }
        yourTextfield.text  = String(yourTextfield.text!.dropFirst(prefix.count).trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines))
    }
}
```